# Logging from the Spring Integration DSL to the database

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm doing the application with the Spring Integration Java DSL.

What is the best way to log to the database using the Spring Data JPA from the application?

I have a quite long integration flow with the multiple HTTP gets and posts. I want at least log the sent and responded messages and which URLs were used and possible some other custom values.

I have tried the logging with the method `IntegrationFlowBuilder.log`. With that my plan would be create some custom logger, which logs to the database.

I have tried the method `IntegrationFlowBuilder.enrichHeaders` with the method `IntegrationFlowBuilder.log` to log the URLSs and the other custom values. How to change some header entry inside the `IntegrationFlowBuilder`? I have added the entry with same key and different value, but the value in the logging doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `HeaderEnricherSpec` for the `enrichHeaders()` provides an option like:

```
/**
 * Determine the default action to take when setting individual header specifications
 * without an explicit 'overwrite' argument.
 * @param defaultOverwrite the defaultOverwrite.
 * @return the header enricher spec.
 * @see HeaderEnricher#setDefaultOverwrite(boolean)
 */
public HeaderEnricherSpec defaultOverwrite(boolean defaultOverwrite) {
```

Also each added entry into the headers can be specified with their own `override` flag:

```
/**
 * Add a single header specification where the value is a String representation of a
 * SpEL {@link Expression}.
 * @param name the header name.
 * @param expression the expression.
 * @param overwrite true to overwrite an existing header.
 * @return the header enricher spec.
 */
public HeaderEnricherSpec headerExpression(String name, String expression, Boolean overwrite) {
```